# Calculation of Confidence Interval for Simulation

Tags: statistics, simulation, binomial-distribution

I wrote a simulation that does 1,000,000 trials.  It returns 430,200 successes.  I want to calculate a probability of success with confidence interval for that probability estimate.

I use $\sigma = \sqrt {np(1-p)} = \sqrt{1e6*0.4302*(1-0.4302)} \approx$  495.1.

Then the probability of success $\approx$ 0.4302 $\pm$ 0.00097, p=0.05.

Is that correct?

Seems weird to me.  Seems like the formula 
$$
\sqrt{np(1-p)}
$$
should be used for a known probability of success and then used to calculate the standard deviation.

In other words, what I want to know is can that same formula be used to go the other direction?  That is, start with a simulated probability of success and use that along with the number of trials to derive the estimated probability of success with confidence interval.

Comment: That is "correct." The caveat is that for smallish sample sizes we need to modify the procedure.  For large $n$, if $a$ is the sample proportion, the estimator $\sqrt{a(1-a)/n}$ for the standard deviation is (almost certainly) plenty good enough. For one thing, taking $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ for $x$ not too far from $1/2$ gives something close to $1/2$. We could have been sloppy about estimating the standard deviation and used $0.5/\sqrt{n}$ without significantly changing the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large $n,$ we have $ \frac{\hat{p} - p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}} \sim N(0,1),$ where $\hat{p}$ is the sampled (simulated) success rate.  Therefore the $100(1-\alpha)$% confidence interval is $$\hat{p} \pm z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}.$$  If you know what the exact value of $p$ is (rare in practice), then you should you the CI above.  Otherwise, you should use 
$$
\hat{p} \pm z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}. 
$$